# codename one - how to check if headphone plugged in

Tags: codenameone

I'm writing a program in Codename One, and my program needs to check if the user plugged in his headphones to his device (Computer/Iphone/ Android).
How can i do that?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the build hints `android.headphoneCallback=true` and `ios.headphoneCallback=true`.

Once you do that you need to add two methods to the main (lifecycle) class:

```
public void headphonesDisconnected() {
}

public void headphonesConnected() {
}
```

These will be invoked appropriately and you can use them to process the event.

See this somewhat old article covering this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/upcoming-features.html